# All strings are unidentified

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    string msg;
    printf("Enter the message that you wish to display as scroller: ");
    getline(cin,msg);
    msg=msg+". ";
    int x=0;
     
    while(1)
    {
        Scroll(msg);
        wait(100);
        system("cls");
                
         x++;    
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I Have this C code and all strings in the file say 'identifier "string" is undefined'. I tried including `<string>` instead of `<string.h>` but it didn't work. Why is it not working?

Comment: There is no type named "string" in the C standard library. Typically one uses `char *` or `const char *`.

Comment: How is this even `C`? Looks `C++` to me.

Comment: I think Albin needs to say whether this is supposed to be C or C++. It has some features of both (eg: `<iostream>` and `printf`).

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes, that answers the question! Thank you!

Comment: To Clarify, i'm using C.

Comment: Someone commented about cs50.h -- are you doing the CS50 course? They use a header with `string` defined as a type.

Comment: No i am not. I'm just getting started with C on my own.

Comment: You should figure out how to make your C compiler accept only C code if you're learning C. eg: `--std=c11` for clang or gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
using namespace std;
```

After includes (but before main). Or, better, use notion of:

```
std::string // instead of string
```

**Update**: I missed the point of this being C-question. I will leave this answer, but for the sake of formality, use it if you came from Google and you are working with C++.

Answer (score -1):

This is C++ code, not C.

The compiler is probably getting confused because it cannot parse it, so then it finds C-like code and all identifiers do not exist.

The includes should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
```

You are also missing a:

```
using namespace std;
```

Plus the definitions for `Scroll` and `wait` etc.

Comment: Please don't recommend `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @cigien I am not recommending it nor arguing for it, that is out of topic. I am just telling OP what the code seems to lack since clearly they didn't write it.

Comment: That's true, you're not *recommending* it, but I think you should actively recommend against it.

Comment: @cigien That is debatable. I don't like `using namespace std;` either, but it is a feature of the language and this is not Code Review SE.